# Can you do PostgreSQL Logical replication with the intention of making source table and target table names different?

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

On PostgreSQL 10 and UP logical replication parameters for publisher and subscription does not seem to have options to specify target table names, just the replication tables.

I know this is a weird scenario to want to have a target table with a different table name but is this possible? is there any other way to do real time replication on a target table with a different name?

SRC DB                       TARGET DB

"TABLE1"  --> REPLICATES ----> "TABLE1A"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; the names of the schema, table and columns have to be the same in both databases.

This is a limitation that may be lifted at some time.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to suggest it on their pipeline? or are there PG related tools that do this?

Comment: You would write to the pgsql-hackers mailing list.